# integer gets promoted to long but not vice versa in Python. Why?

Tags: python, types

When the value of an number goes beyond the `integer` range, python promotes it to a `long`.  But when the value comes back to the integer range, why doesn't it get demoted to an `int`?

```
>>> i=2147483647
>>> type(i)
<type 'int'>
>>> i = i + 1
>>> type(i)
<type 'long'>
>>> i = i - 10
>>> type(i)
<type 'long'>
>>> i
2147483638L
>>>
```

Comment: I just thought it would make sense to demote it.

Comment: "make sense to demote"?  How?  It would lose information.  Anything larger than 2147483647 cannot be "demoted" without losing some part of the value.  Can you explain how that would make sense?

Comment: The OP's question specifies quite clearly that he's talking about longs which are small enough to be demoted without losing any information. I'd guess a possible explination is that detecting that longs are small enough, and then performing the conversion (potentially several times, as the value rises and falls) was judged to be more complex and expensive than simply leaving the value as a long once it had been promoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [python source](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5.6/) (in file Objects/longobject.c):

```
static PyLongObject *
x_add(PyLongObject *a, PyLongObject *b)
{
    Py_ssize_t size_a = ABS(a->ob_size), size_b = ABS(b->ob_size);
    PyLongObject *z;
    int i;
    digit carry = 0;

    /* Ensure a is the larger of the two: */
    if (size_a < size_b) {
        { PyLongObject *temp = a; a = b; b = temp; }
        { Py_ssize_t size_temp = size_a;
          size_a = size_b;
          size_b = size_temp; }
    }
    z = _PyLong_New(size_a+1);
    if (z == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < size_b; ++i) {
        carry += a->ob_digit[i] + b->ob_digit[i];
        z->ob_digit[i] = carry & MASK;
        carry >>= SHIFT;
    }
    for (; i < size_a; ++i) {
        carry += a->ob_digit[i];
        z->ob_digit[i] = carry & MASK;
        carry >>= SHIFT;
    }
    z->ob_digit[i] = carry;
    return long_normalize(z);
}

/* Subtract the absolute values of two integers. */

static PyLongObject *
x_sub(PyLongObject *a, PyLongObject *b)
{
    Py_ssize_t size_a = ABS(a->ob_size), size_b = ABS(b->ob_size);
    PyLongObject *z;
    Py_ssize_t i;
    int sign = 1;
    digit borrow = 0;

    /* Ensure a is the larger of the two: */
    if (size_a < size_b) {
        sign = -1;
        { PyLongObject *temp = a; a = b; b = temp; }
        { Py_ssize_t size_temp = size_a;
          size_a = size_b;
          size_b = size_temp; }
    }
    else if (size_a == size_b) {
        /* Find highest digit where a and b differ: */
        i = size_a;
        while (--i >= 0 && a->ob_digit[i] == b->ob_digit[i])
            ;
        if (i < 0)
            return _PyLong_New(0);
        if (a->ob_digit[i] < b->ob_digit[i]) {
            sign = -1;
            { PyLongObject *temp = a; a = b; b = temp; }
        }
        size_a = size_b = i+1;
    }
    z = _PyLong_New(size_a);
    if (z == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < size_b; ++i) {
        /* The following assumes unsigned arithmetic
           works module 2**N for some N>SHIFT. */
        borrow = a->ob_digit[i] - b->ob_digit[i] - borrow;
        z->ob_digit[i] = borrow & MASK;
        borrow >>= SHIFT;
        borrow &= 1; /* Keep only one sign bit */
    }
    for (; i < size_a; ++i) {
        borrow = a->ob_digit[i] - borrow;
        z->ob_digit[i] = borrow & MASK;
        borrow >>= SHIFT;
        borrow &= 1; /* Keep only one sign bit */
    }
    assert(borrow == 0);
    if (sign < 0)
        z->ob_size = -(z->ob_size);
    return long_normalize(z);
}
```

Note that the return types of both procedures are `PyLongObject *`.

What this shows is that addition and subtraction of `long`s yield more `long`s in python, regardless of whether the values could fit in ints.

Example:

```
>>> 3L + 4L
7L
```

And [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#coercion-rules) are python's coercion rules, specifically:

> For objects x and y, first `x.__add__(y)` is tried. If this is not
>   implemented or returns `NotImplemented`, `y.__add__(x)` is tried. If this
>   is also not implemented or returns NotImplemented, a TypeError
>   exception is raised.

So doing `i - 10`, where `i` is a `long`, results in another `long`.

Answer (score 4):

Promoting an `int` to a `long` doesn't lose any information and is necessary to store bigger numbers.

Demoting isn't necessary and wouldn't have any real advantage - other than saving 4bytes of memory - which isn't really a priority in an interpreted language.

Comment: *wouldn't have any real advantage - other than saving 4bytes of memory*  -- Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

As further evidence of the python development team's thinking on int vs long, in python 3 int and long are unified.

http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers